# eclipse.ini not detecting jvm on Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have a custom eclipse IDE which is based on v4.4.0. I don't have any java pre-installed in my Mac OS (EI Capitan v10.11). I have a jre(1.8.0_20) in a location which I want to start the eclipse with. So, i go and edit the eclipse.ini file with the vm args

```
-vm 
/Users/abbas/Desktop/jre1.8.0_20.jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

This is before the -vmargs argument

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
com.myos.ide.package.commercial.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/Users/abbas/Desktop/jre1.8.0_20.jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Now, when I try to start it by clicking on the .app file still gives me the pop-up

`"To open “WebOSIDE” you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime."`

I have verified that the java in the path above works

```
/Users/abbas/Desktop/jre1.8.0_20.jre/Contents/Home/bin/java -version java version "1.8.0_25" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_25-b17) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

I've tried on Mac High Sierra and the behaviour is same.

What could be the problem ?

Update : When I try to launch eclipse by navigating to WebOSIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/WebOSIDE and then clicking on WebOSIDE then it launches and it indeed takes the path of the jre specified in the ini file. But for some reason clicking on .app file isnt launching

Comment: I think this was a problem with RCPs built with older versions of Eclipse such as the one you are using. It is fixed by using an up to date version of Eclipse for the RCP.

Comment: @greg-449 Is there a reference link for the same ?

Comment: There are some bug reports in Eclipse Bugzilla such as [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475640).

Answer (score 1):

By default, eclipse will use the ini file with the same name as the executable. Not sure what the name of your executable is. If it is `WebOSIDE` then, by default, eclipse will look for a `WebOSIDE.ini` file. I'm not totally up to speed with where eclipse will look for that ini file though it may depend on the release of eclipse that your app is based on. Currently, it seems to be `Contents/eclipse`).

The location and name of the ini file can be changed  using the `launcher.ini` argument for running the executable (you can also use this on the command line to check it). I'm not too familiar with this but I think the following (as an example) can be added to the `Contents/info.plist` file:

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
  <array>
    <string>--launcher.ini</string>
    <string>$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/Profile/eclipse.ini</string>
  <array>
```

If it's not finding the ini file then MacOS may be prompting you if there is no Java properly installed. Avoid installing the legacy Java runtime as it may be difficult to get rid of.

This is essentially from memory so search for more details on specifying the location of the ini file.

Comment: I tried with the --launcher.ini argument in the info.plist file  with $APP_PACKAGE/Contents/MacOS/WebOSIDE.ini and it does take that when I launch using the executable WebOSIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/WebOSIDE . I am able to launch it this way but  doesn't work when I launch via the WebOSIDE.app, still gives me the same error. I can confirm that it does take the launcher.ini argument because if i give a wrong path in that and launch via the executable, it throws me the error as told before.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure of all the fine details of how the eclipse.ini file is located on the Mac. I know that, by default, the name of the ini file should be the same as the name of the executable, but a lot of how this works seems to have changed some time last year. So perhaps try renaming the file `WebOSIDE.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

For a Mac, install a JDK. It doesn't really have a way of enumerating JREs to applications.

Comment: I know I could make this work with an installed JDK but the idea is to use the provided JRE.